# Vlookup not pulling data from the destination source

Tags: error-handling, vlookup

Sub Button4 Click()

On Error GoTo Msg

Dim x As Integer, erow As Integer, lrow As Integer

erow = Sheets("XYZ").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lrow=Sheets("ABC").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To erow

Sheets("XYZ").Range ("G" & x) = WorksheetFunction. VLookup (Sheets("XYZ").Range("D" & x), Sheets("ABC").Range("A2:C" & erow), 2, 0)

Next x

Exit Sub

Msg: (Sheets("XYZ").Range("G" & x) = "N/A"

Resume Next

End Sub

Whenever trying to run the above code it's directly getting me to the MSG and returning value as N/A considered as an error.